# We have n cards. We want to split them into an even number of non-empty subsets, form a line within each subset, then arrange the subsets in a line.

Tags: combinatorics, recurrence-relations, generating-functions

From A Walk Through Combinatorics by Bona in the section on generating functions

> We have n cards. We want to split them into an even number of non-empty subsets, form a line within each subset, then arrange the subsets in a line. In how many different ways can we do this?

My immediate reaction was to set $a_n=n!$ for $ n\ge2 $ and  $b_n =\begin{cases}
0,  & \text{if $n$ is odd} \\
n!, & \text{if $n$ is even}  \\
\end{cases}$

And use the exponential compositional formula $G(x)=B(A(x))$ but I realized that this won't work as this counts the number of cards inside each subset as even versus the number of subsets as even. I also failed trying to find a recurrence relation.

Also, on a related problem I ended up with the recurrence relation for the exponential series $G(x)$ as $g_{n+1}=ng_n+ \binom{n}{2}g_{n-2}$. I've had difficulty doing the algebra to show $$G(x)=\frac{e^{-x/2-x^2/4}}{\sqrt{1-x}}$$

from this recurrence relation, help would be greatly appreciated. I've gotten it to

$$G(x)-1=\sum_{n \ge0}\big(ng_{n+2}+ {n \choose 2}g_n)\frac{x^{n+3}}{(n+3)!} $$

and not quite sure where to go with that.

Answer (score 2):

My answer pretty much repeats the content of [Marko's deleted answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/44883/marko-riedel).

Recall the Compositional formula for exponential generating functions (Theorem 8.27).

> Suppose there are $a_n$ ways to build an $A$-structure on an $n$-element set, where $a_0=0$.
> Suppose there are $b_n$ ways to build an $B$-structure on an $n$-element set, where $b_0=1$.
> Let $c_n$ be the number of ways to partition an $n$ element set into nonempty subsets, then build an $A$-structure on each of the subsets, and finally build a $B$-structure on the set of subsets. Finally, suppose that $A(x)$ is the exponential generating function for $(a_n)_{n\ge 0}$, and similarly for $B(x)$ with $(b_n)_{n\ge 0}$ and $C(x)$ for $(c_n)_{n\ge 0}$. Then
> $$C(x)=(B \circ A)(x)=B(A(x)).$$

To apply this to your problem, you should use
$$A(x)=\sum_{n\ge 1} n! \cdot \frac{x^n}{n!}=\frac{x}{1-x},$$ because on each of the subsets, you are building a linear order, and there are $n!$ linear orders. Note we start at $n=1$, because each subset must be nonempty, so $n=0$ is not allowed. Then, $$B(x)=\sum_{n\ge 0}(2n)!\cdot \frac{x^{2n}}{(2n)!}=\frac{1}{1-x^2}$$ Similarly, the collection of subsets is being linearly ordered, but this time, we stipulate that there must be an even number of subsets, so all odd coefficients must be replaced with $0$. Finally, we get
$$
\begin{align}
c_n 
&=n![x^n]B(A(x))
\\&=n![x^n]\;\frac1{1-\left(\frac{x}{1-x}\right)^2}
\\&=n![x^n] \frac{(1-x)^2}{1-2x}
\\&=n!(2^n-2\cdot 2^{n-1}+2^{n-2})=\boxed{ n!2^{n-2} }.
\end{align}
$$
Finally, we can give a combinatorial proof of this formula. There are $n!$ ways to arrange these $n$ cards in a row. When you do this, there are $n-1$ spaces between adjacent cards. If you select an odd number of these spaces, and put dividers in those spaces, then the entire line is divided into an even number of linearly ordered subsets, as required. Note that there are $2^{n-2}$ odd subsets of an $(n-1)$-element set. This is why $n!\cdot 2^{n-2}$ is the answer.

Comment: hi Mike, I could not exactly remember (and see) what I wrote as comment, but I guess I assumed that the number elements in each subset must be even. Can you explain my previous comment

Comment: @NotaSalmonFish Here is a screenshot of the deleted answer and comments:  https://i.stack.imgur.com/Uph6V.png I should not have made such a big deal out of it; you just mistakenly said that the inner generating function should be $1/(1-x)$, when Marko was correct that it should be $x/(1-x)$. You need to zero out the coefficient of $x^0$ to make the compositional lemma work.

Comment: actually it seems that it is because of my english understading. I am not native one and I sometimes mistakely interpret the words. As I wrote above, I assumed that the question meant that we try to separate the elements into those subsets which includes even number of elements in it. because of that reason $A(x)= x^2/(1-x^2)$.. But, the question actually ask that the number of subsets must be even.. I owe apology to Marko :))

Comment: I translated "even number subsets" as the subsets which contain even number of elements.. By the way, thanks for screenshot $+1$

Answer (score 1):

We're in the same class! I am too struggling with the same problem. As for the second problem you referenced, after multiplying your recurrence relation by $\frac{x^{(n+2)}}{(n+2)!}$ and summing for all n, decompose it to a differential equation of $\frac{G'(x)}{G(x)}$ and solve from there. Hopefully that hint will help.

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE! Here's a quick guide on how to write math on this site: http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: Thank you for the edit, Newb. And Eric, if you are able to solve your problem, please report back!

Comment: I'm not any farther than what I've edited in on the second question. On the first one I found this link that may help, page 7, $e^{cosh(x)-1}$: http://math.berkeley.edu/~mhaiman/math172-spring10/exponential.pdf I'm trying to find a way to adapt it for this problem but the forming a line within each subset part is tripping me up.

Comment: Wouldn't the ways to form a line within each subset simply be (n!) ? The part that I don't understand is splitting [n] into an even number of subsets.

Comment: As for the link you found, that details how to create blocks of even size, not to split into an even number of blocks.

Comment: Since both the number of ways to line up cards, as well as ways to line up the subsets is n!, the answer should be G( (n!)! ), where G(x) is how to partition the cards into an even number of subsets. I just can't figure out G(x)....