# Number of ways for splitting elements into non-empty subsets, forming a line within eachnsubset, then arranging the subsets in a line

Tags: combinatorics, generating-functions

I have been trying to solve this problem in the book A Walkthrough Combinatorics. However, I am struggling. There is a [duplicate](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/553552/we-have-n-cards-we-want-to-split-them-into-an-even-number-of-non-empty-subsets) but it has never been answered.

> We have n cards. We want to split them into an even number of non-empty subsets, form a line within each subset, and then arrange the subsets in a line. In how many different ways can we do this?

I think I should use the composition rule of generating functions. Taking $A_n(x)$  (forming a line within each subset, which is an even number)  = $\sum_{n\geq0} 2^{2n-1} x^{2n}$, and $B_n(x)$ (arranging subsets in a line) = $\sum_{n\geq0} n! x^{2n}$

I think $a_n$ should be $2^{n-1}$ since this is how many lines we can form from n elements. Is this true? I feel like there are some huge parts missing.

Comment: As was mentioned in the duplicate, this appears to be [A014297](https://oeis.org/A014297)

Comment: I just posted an answer to the older question. Assuming you find that satisfactory, I will close this question as a duplicate of the old one.

Comment: @MikeEarnest the answer was satisfactory, you can close the question!